# Error with dbplyr compute where temporary = false on newest version of R

Tags: r, dbplyr

This morning I've installed the newest version of R (4.2.1). When using dbplyr everything works fine except for the compute function in the dbplyr package.

When I run something like

```
df %>% compute(in_schema("schema", "table"), temporary = FALSE)
```

Until recently it was working fine, after the updates I get the error:

```
Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1594: 42601: [Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState 42601] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NULL"
LINE 2: NULL.NULL AS
        ^
```

I'm using R version 4.2.1 and dbplyr version 4.2.1. A colleague who is running R 4.2.0 is getting the same error.

Is this a known error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you make this more reproducible? It seems as if your `df` is somehow corrupted.

Comment: @r2evans It seems to happen irrespective of the dataframe that I've been using. I also got a colleague to run one of scripts that I was having issues with and it worked fine for them.

Comment: Whenever you feel like this: "Until recently it was working fine, after the updates I get the error:" it is a strong sign to explore `renv` package!

Comment: Depending on the names of your `schema` and `table`, you may need to wrap these in `sql( )`.  The way dbplyr prepares these inputs changed in one of the more recent versions of the package.

Answer (score 0):

This happens dbplyr 2.2.1 with passing `in_schema` to compute ([relevant line](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/v2.2.1/R/verb-compute.R#L42)). The call to `unname` returns `NULL.NULL` instead of the proper name.

This is fixed in the main branch now but is currently unreleased. Probably the best interim option is to force install the development version of dbplyr using `devtools::install_github`. The other option would be to create a local version of the function mirroring the new compute functionality and call that instead.